# Using include doesn't change the behavior

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Could Someone help me to clarify the difference between :

```
 var query = awlt.People.Include(p => p.EmailAddresses)
                    .Where(p => p.LastName.Equals(lastName))
                    .SelectMany(a => a.EmailAddresses)
                    .Select(a => a.EmailAddress1);
```

---

```
 var query = awlt.People
                    .Where(p => p.LastName.Equals(lastName))
                    .SelectMany(a => a.EmailAddresses)
                    .Select(a => a.EmailAddress1);
```

---

I get the same results in both cases without knowing the difference .
Does the Eager Loading require using `Include` ?

Comment: Which version of EF? In versions prior 7, both will work the same. The only difference would be returning the `People` collection without any other querying. Then `EmailAddresses` would be populated only if they are invoked (lazy)

Comment: @RoyalBg : I use version 6.1.3, Could you explain more the difference?

Comment: Let's say you need to serialize `awlt.People` query's result. Without include you will not recieve the email addresses. But if you invoke them before the serialization (in this case `Select`), you will recieve them, so you don't need include. In version 7 you always need include (or so it was a month ago)

Comment: @RoyalBg: thanks a lot, Could we consider the second query as eager loading also ?

Comment: the second query is (by definition) lazy loading. to be fair, your first query is eager loading, but on the INVERSE navigation property, which makes no difference. To elaborate a bit: you tell EF you want specific People - so EF will query the People table and eventually load these into context. of these people however, you only need the EmailAddresses - so EF will join to EMailAddresses and populate the context accordingly. the Include() statement does not change anything: the included property is already in the context. Also all people are in the context, so the output is the same.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare you put a bounty so can you clarify what is still not clear for you?

Comment: @Evk : i want to know what's the difference between the two queries mainly from performance perspective

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare In EF6, since these do the same thing, I would assume the query with less specificity (without Include) will be faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The both query are retrieving the related data just first query by using [**Eager Loading**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) (and yes *Eager loading* is achieved by use of the `Include` method as you guessed) and the second query by using [**Lazy loading**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx) which is by default. But since your query will only returns `EmailAddresses` because of the `Select()` and `SelectMany()` operations **the `Include()` method doesn't change the behavior**. To see **when** `Include()` method is matter in your example read the following lines that I will prove it in one example:

To know some difference between this two kind of loading related entities **Eager loading** is typically more efficient when you need the related data for all retrieved rows of the primary table. And also when relations **are** **not** too much, *eager loading* will be good practice to reduce further queries on server. But when you know that you will not need a property instantly then lazy loading maybe a good choice. And also eager loading is a good choice in a situation where your db context would be disposed and lazy loading could not take place anymore.
To prove that one is Lazy Loading and one is Eager Loading consider the following code:

```
public List<Person> GetEmailAddresses()
{
    using (yourEntities awlt = new yourEntities())
    {
        var query = awlt.People
                .Where(p => p.LastName.Equals(lastName));
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

After calling this method, You cannot load the related entity lazily because the db is disposed. To prove try this:

```
var query = GetEmailAddresses();
foreach (var item in query.SelectMany(a => a.EmailAddresses).Select(a => a.EmailAddress1))
{
    MessageBox.Show(item);                
}
```

And you will get this error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

But if you change the `GetEmailAddresses` to use Eager Loading like this:

```
public List<Person> GetEmailAddresses()
{
    using (yourEntities awlt = new yourEntities())
    {
        var query = awlt.People.Include("EmailAddresses")
                .Where(p => p.LastName.Equals(lastName));
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then the below code should works fine:

```
var query = GetEmailAddresses();
foreach (var item in query.SelectMany(a => a.EmailAddresses).Select(a => a.EmailAddress1))
{
    MessageBox.Show(item);                
}
```

So in a situation where your db context would be disposed the **Eager Loading** would be a better choice.

Comment: By the way technical term for Lazy loading is  [Deffered execution] I would rather use that.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about EF 7, but in EF 6 both those statements produce the same queries to database and so are essentially the same. There is no lazy loading, no eager loading (in a sense this term is usually used) whatsoever.

You need to `Include` only properties of entities you *materialize*. In the example above you materialize `Person.EmailAddresses.EmailAddress1`, but you include just `Person.EmailAddresses` - this has no effect (for more details see for example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include/)).

Consider this sample code (details does not matter, there is just Error entity with Code navigation property):

```
// note we materialized query 
var errors = ctx.Errors.Include(c => c.Code).ToArray();
// no lazy loading happens here - we already loaded all related Codes with Include
var codeIds = errors.Select(c => c.Code.CodeID).ToArray();
```

And this one:

```
// no need to include here!
var codeIds = ctx.Errors.Select(c =>c.Code.CodeID).ToArray();
```

And with include:

```
// include has no effect here!
var codeIds = ctx.Errors.Inlcude(c => c.Code).Select(c => c.Code.CodeID).ToArray();
```

What is eager loading? It's when you include additional data to the related entity using `Include` statement. Here Include statement has **no** effect, it's just does nothing, so we cannot name that eager loading.

What is lazy loading? It's when navigation property is loading when you access it for the first time. You do not do this in your examples, so there is no lazy loading either.

Both examples just execute identical queries to database (after you materialize them with enumeration`ToArray` etc).

Comment: I have two entities `People` & `EmailAddresses` 1-M

Comment: I understand but this changes nothing - Include has no effect in your case. You can verify this yourself by running both statements and logging generated SQL for them. I just used more simple example in my answer to clarify when Include _does_ have effect.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the two queries is exactly the same (also about 'eager' and 'lazy' load).
In this case I think that also the query are very similar or the same BUT never trust EF Provider generated queries. To see the generated queries you can stop the program with a breakpoint and have a look to query object (pointing the mouse on it). That is the query generated by EF Provider.

About Eager loading (the Include statement) in this case it should not be useful because is used to load properties of the output object. In this case you are selecting EMailAddress1 so with Include you could eager load properties of EMailAddress1 (and avoid lazy queries during EMailAddress1 access).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference if you look into SQL Server Profiler after the query is run. So in your first case there is only one query going to your database and fetching records from People table as well as EmailAddresses table whereas in the second case it does two queries to database and fetches People first and then EmailAddresses in a second query. Thus the first scenario is called eager loading and the second one lazy loading.