# DbContext has been disposed despite calling ToList within using statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am seeing a **The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.** exception message even though the code is using eager loading by returning **List<T>**.  I have the following code in an **EntityRepository** class:

```
public List<Entity> GetEntityByProperty(string property)
{
    using (AppDbContext appDbContext = GetContext())
    {
        List<Entity> entities = appDbContext.Entities
            .Where(e => e.Property == property)
            .ToList();

        return entities;
    }
}
```

This is in turn being called from a web service class:

```
private static EntityRepository EntityRepositoryStatic = new EntityRepository();

[WebMethod]
public List<Entity> GetEntityByProperty(string property)
{
    return EntityRepositoryStatic.GetEntityByProperty(property);
}
```

The **EntityRepository** inherits from a **Repository** base class which implements **IDisposable** (to dispose the context) and has this code to return an instance of the context:

```
private AppDbContext appDbContext;

public AppDbContext GetContext()
{
    if (appDbContext == null)
    {
        appDbContext = new AppDbContext();
    }

    return appDbContext;
}
```

The exception is thrown on the line making the call to **appDbContext** in the repository.  Am I missing something obvious?

This is a large legacy codebase therefore we are simply trying to replace inline calls to the context in the web service with calls to the repository classes instead.

Comment: You didn't use the *eager loading* here. After calling this method, You cannot load the related entity lazily because the db is disposed and so the Eager Loading would be a better choice here. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34628138/2946329

Comment: Or maybe this will be helpful also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961249/using-include-doesnt-change-the-behavior

Comment: Sorry - misprint in `GetContext()` - should be `appDbContext` - I'll update it now.

Comment: @BWHazel Well you need to use `Include` to use *eager loading* and get rid of this error. Check the examples I linked to know how and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `GetContext()` you create a new context, then you return it, then it's used and disposed of.  Then the next call to `GetContext()` returns the original, already disposed, context, and you get an error.  If you want to re-use it, you can't dispose it; if you want to dispose of it when done, you can't re-use it.

Comment: OP please review this solution it is correct, since you are using a Repository  beyond a call and internally disposing the shared context in first call, thus an exception. Ideally Context shall get disposed on disposing the EntityRepository object, not in every call.