# issue with using DbContext and returning view with the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to fetch something from the database and return that with the model if `ModelState` is not valid, however I seem to not be able to use `using` and I want to.

So this code works:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditProduct(ProductVM productVM, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            // Check model state
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Db db = new Db();
                productVM.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");

                return View(productVM);

            }

            return View(productVM);
        }
```

And this code throws the following error:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(ProductVM productVM, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Check model state
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            //Db db = new Db();
            productVM.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");
        }

        return View(productVM);

    }

    return View(productVM);
}
```

Can I somehow use `using` and still have it work?

Comment: try `db.Categories.ToList();`

Comment: Seems to be working! What does that have to do with the DbContext being disposed?

Comment: You do not really need `using`, but if your do then you must materialize the collection using `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: After calling this method, You cannot load the related entity lazily because the db is disposed but if you use **Eager Loading** and `Include` it should works. See here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961249/using-include-doesnt-change-the-behavior

Comment: Thank you both. So should I just not use `using` from now on at all with EF? It would be easier for me not to use it, but I thought it was recommended, that's why I am pushing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stephen Muecke said you must materialize the collection using `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()`. If you don't enumarate the collection, it won't run immediately. That's why you are getting that error. So it should be;

```
productVM.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
```

Hope helps,